# ¿Por que el tamaño de un array que paso como argumento es 32?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo la duda de por que al pasar un arreglo a la siguiente función, al imprimir en consola el tamaño del mismo es 32, siendo que el tamaño que toma el arreglo antes de pasarlo como argumento a la función es el numero de elementos que desee agregar el usuario:

```
void elevar_cubo(float arreglo[])
{
    float arreglo_al_cubo[sizeof(arreglo)];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arreglo); i++)
    {
        arreglo_al_cubo[i] = pow(arreglo[i], 3);
    }

    cout << "el tamaño del areglo al cubo es: " << sizeof(arreglo_al_cubo) << endl;

    cout << "El arreglo al cubo es: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arreglo); i++)
    {
        cout << arreglo_al_cubo[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

y esta es la función main:

```
int main()
{
    int cantidad_elementos;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de elementos que desea que contenga el arreglo: " << endl;
    cin >> cantidad_elementos;

float arreglo[cantidad_elementos];

for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_elementos; i++)
{
    cout << "Ingrese el valor " << i + 1 << " del arreglo: " << endl;
    cin >> arreglo[i];
}

cout << "El arreglo que ingreso es: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_elementos; i++)
{
    cout << arreglo[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;

elevar_cubo(arreglo);

return 0
}
```

Esto hace que el arreglo local de la funcion elevar_cubo este lleno de varios 0s.

Comment: no conozco C++ pero si C. Lo que dice en la w3s es que sizeof devuelve el tamaño de un tipo de dato en bytes y no el tamaño del array en si, pero se puede solucionar muy facil leelo: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_arrays_size.asp

Comment: porque en c++ los arrays son punteros y el tamaño que te arroja sizeof es el tamaño de un puntero a float, la solucion es facil, la funcion elevar_cubo debe recibir dos parametros, el de tu array y el tamaño del mismo.

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego no existe ningún dato básico en [tag:c++] cuyo tamaño en bytes sea 32.

Comment: @Accimus `sizeof` devuelve el tamaño en bytes no en bits. El `sizeof` de un puntero debería ser `4` en caso de punteros de 32 bits i `8` en caso de punteros de 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no se pueden pasar formaciones<sup>1</sup> por copia:

```
void elevar_cubo(float arreglo[])
/*               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Formación de 'float' con cantidad
                                     de elementos desconocida. */
```

Lo que sucede en ese caso es que la formación se transforma en un puntero, esta característica se conoce como "[*decaída a puntero*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)", por lo que la función se transforma en:

```
void elevar_cubo(float *arreglo)
```

Así que `sizeof(arreglo)` no está consultando la **longitud** de la formación, está consultando el **tamaño** del puntero. De hecho, no se puede saber la longitud de una formación en base a un puntero y tampoco puedes definir formaciones cuyo tamaño sea una variable:

```
int cantidad_elementos;
cin >> cantidad_elementos;
// Este código no es estándar, 'cantidad_elementos' es una variable
float arreglo[cantidad_elementos];
```

Si necesitas una colección de datos de tamaño arbitrario, usa un contenedor:

```
void elevar_cubo(std::vector<float> &arreglo)
{
    std::vector<float> arreglo_al_cubo(arreglo.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.size(); i++)
    {
        arreglo_al_cubo[i] = pow(arreglo[i], 3);
    }

    cout << "el tamaño del areglo al cubo es: " << arreglo_al_cubo.size() << endl;

    cout << "El arreglo al cubo es: " << endl;
    for (const auto &valor : arreglo_al_cubo)
    {
        cout << valor << ' ';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int cantidad_elementos;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de elementos que desea que contenga el arreglo:\n"
    cin >> cantidad_elementos;

    std::vector<float> arreglo(cantidad_elementos);

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_elementos; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el valor " << i + 1 << " del arreglo:\n";
        cin >> arreglo[i];
    }

    cout << "El arreglo que ingreso es: " << endl;
    for (const auto &valor : arreglo)
    {
        cout << arreglo[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    elevar_cubo(arreglo);

    return 0
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.